# CSS Rotated Text exceeding row height

Tags: css

I have the following text ("Job Offered"), and am trying to make it so it does not get cut off as you can see. It is rotated so it exceeds the boundary of its row.

[image]

My code is currently as follows:

**html**

```
<div id="fade-in"><p *ngIf="jobModel.type === 1">Job Offered</p></div>
```

**css**

```
#fade-in p {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    animation: fadein 8s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 8s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 8s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 8s; /* Opera */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-35deg);
}
```

If anyone can assist on how I can get the full text to appear without having to increase the height of the row if possible, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I think the size of your row should be auto to give the text some space when it is rotating

Comment: You could do the "job" above "offered".

Comment: `overflow:visible` on whichever element is cropping it.